# F# for loop error

Tags: for-loop, f#, type-mismatch

I was playing around F# and noticed a problem I cannot understand. Say I want get a series of integer inputs from the user and store it in an array:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main =
    let n = Console.ReadLine() |> int
    let inputVals = Array.zeroCreate n
    for i in 0 .. n - 1 do
        inputVals.[i] <- (Console.ReadLine() |> int)
    printf "%A\n" inputVals 
    0 //compiler error here. The type does not match the expected type
```

But this gives the error

```
This expression was expected to have type string [] -> int but here has type int
```

After some playing around I suspect the error is coming from the for loop. But I cannot figure out why it expects a string[] -> int. This seems like a very simple problem but I just can figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error here is unrelated to the loop itself. You are using `main` as a value, but it should be a *function* from array of strings into `int`.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    // Your stuff here
    0
```

where `args` will be inferred as `string[]`.
If you are feeling verbose, you can spell it out:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main (args : string[]) =
    // Your stuff here
    0
```

Everything else is fine.

Comment: Thank, that did the trick. Does this mean F# does not allow the entry point to not have input arguments. Basically is this possible in F# : `public static void Main()` ?

Comment: @mashrur I'm pretty sure you cannot do that. Entry point function signature is [`string[] -> int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402151.aspx) and that's it :)

Comment: @mashrur The arguments are always there, but you can of course ignore them: `let main _ = ...`

Comment: @mashrur the syntax analogous to `public static int Main() { return 0; }` would be `let main () = 0`.  If you try replacing `args` with `()`, you'll get a compiler error indicating that this is not allowed in F#: "This expression was expected to have type string [] but here has type unit"